# Calculate Average Estimate ignore zero values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, math, count, average

Im trying to calculate the average (estimated) HbA1c but the Overall count includes the 0 values.
The over all count's max values is 7 if all 7 bb,ab,bl,al,bs,as,o has values.

The problem is if one is blank the over all count still divides by 7 which in return makes the estimate value incorrect

`

```
        let averages = BloodGlucoseModel.history.reduce(
        (acc, el) => {
        if (el.bb !== 0) {
        acc.bb.count += 1;
        acc.bb.total += el.bb;
        }

        if (el.ab !== 0) {
        acc.ab.count += 1;
        acc.ab.total += el.ab;
        }

        if (el.bl !== 0) {
        acc.bl.count += 1;
        acc.bl.total += el.bl;
        }

        if (el.al !== 0) {
        acc.al.count += 1;
        acc.al.total += el.al;
        }

        if (el.bs !== 0) {
        acc.bs.count += 1;
        acc.bs.total += el.bs;
        }

        if (el.as !== 0) {
        acc.as.count += 1;
        acc.as.total += el.as;
        }

        if (el.o !== 0) {
        acc.o.count += 1;
        acc.o.total += el.o;
        }

        return acc;
        },
        {
        bb: { total: 0, count: 0 },
        ab: { total: 0, count: 0 },
        bl: { total: 0, count: 0 },
        al: { total: 0, count: 0 },
        bs: { total: 0, count: 0 },
        as: { total: 0, count: 0 },
        o: { total: 0, count: 0 },
        }
        );

        let overallTotal =
        averages.bb.total +
        averages.ab.total +
        averages.bl.total +
        averages.al.total +
        averages.bs.total +
        averages.as.total +
        averages.o.total;
        let overallCount =
        averages.bb.count +
        averages.ab.count +
        averages.bl.count +
        averages.al.count +
        averages.bs.count +
        averages.as.count +
        averages.o.count;

        let estimatedHbA1c =
        overallCount > 0 ? ((overallTotal / overallCount) * 18 + 46.7) / 28.7 : 0;
```

`

Comment: I'm certain this can be simplified, but we need to see your actual data to provide a better solution. Can you please edit the question to include at least a basic example of the data in `BloodGlucoseModel.history` and also an expected output to confirm accuracy